# jquery datetimepicker change dataformat

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to change the dataformat as: 15/06/2018 22:00 but i get: 2018/06/15 22:00

```
<input id="datetime">

<script>
$(function() {
      $('#datetime').datetimepicker({Format: 'dd/mm/yy hh:ii'});
});
</script>
```

Thank you so much for your help and tips.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: In `datetimerpicker` the option is `format:`, not `Format:`. It's case-sensitive.

Comment: See the example here: https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

Comment: @Barmar thank you, still problem with the format

Comment: Try `d/m/Y h:i`

Comment: yes, find the solution: is    lang:'ru'

Comment: Actually I think it's `d/m/Y H:i`. It uses the same format as PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing **'dd/mm/yy hh:ii'** with **default** for format.